# Applying an image file using ImageX script gives boot configuration data store could not be opened error with new PC

Tags: windows-7, bcd, bcdedit, imagex

I am applying windows image files, wim files, using Microsoft ImageX.  This used to work fine but on a new version of what should be the same PC it now fails.

The script is like this:

```
DISKPART /s WipeDisk.txt
D:
ImageX /apply MyImage.wim 1 c:\
bcdedit /set {default} device partition=c:
bcdedit /set {default} osdevice partition=c:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=c:
```

and WipeDisk.txt is like this:

```
SELECT DISK 0
CLEAN
CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY
FORMAT QUICK FS=NTFS LABEL="Windows"
ACTIVE
ASSIGN LETTER="C"
```

The error after applying the image is:

```
all the diskpart stuff works fine

[ 100% ] Applying progress

Successfully applied image.

Total elapsed time: 17 min 18 sec

D:\>bcdedit /set {default} device partition=c:
The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The requested system device cannot be found.
D:\>bcdedit /set {default} osdevice partition=c:
The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The requested system device cannot be found.
D:\>bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=c:
The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The requested system device cannot be found.
```

And if I try to boot the PC after applying the image I get error:

```
Status: 0xc0000185

Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

Then I hit enter and see:

```
File: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc0000185
Info: An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.
```

This is the target hardware PC used:
http://www.axiomtek.com/DownLoad/Spec/got3187w-834-pct.pdf

Is there an alternative to BCDEdit I could use?  Any way to fix the disk not booting?